# Python - OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application when trying to use fluidsynth from mingus.midi

Tags: python, package, fluidsynth

I am Working on Windows 10 with 64 Bit.
I want to use the mingus package for python in my jupyter notebook. But i have problems running the fluidsynth library.

I followed the instructions on this website to install fluidsynth:
https://bspaans.github.io/python-mingus/doc/wiki/tutorialSetup.html

If i try to import fluidsynth with:

```
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6003c50a6278> in <module>
----> 1 from mingus.midi import fluidsynth

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\mingus\midi\fluidsynth.py in <module>
     35 import wave
     36 
---> 37 from mingus.midi import pyfluidsynth as fs
     38 from mingus.midi.sequencer import Sequencer
     39 

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\mingus\midi\pyfluidsynth.py in <module>
     41     raise ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
     42 
---> 43 _fl = CDLL(lib)
     44 
     45 

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    346 
    347         if handle is None:
--> 348             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    349         else:
    350             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I dont know what the problem is. I already read some stackoverflow questions regarding this error, but i dont understand how i can fix my problem.

I am not sure if the fluidsynth, which i got from QSynth is used here.

Has anybody an Idea? Im not a very experienced programmer, so it could also be a small simple error.

Im glad for everybody who can help me!